# Слово "намекнуть": примеры употребления

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

Скажите, пожалуйста, верно ли употребление слова *"намекнуть"* в предложении.

*Рассеянное облако бабочек намекнуло идти к переливающейся двери впереди.*

В словарях встречала примеры употребления: *намекнуть на что-то, побудить к чему-то.* Может, тогда стоит так сформулировать: ... *намекнуло, что нужно идти*? Или *намекнуло идти* тоже верно?

Comment: *намекнуло идти* лучше, потому что безличное. А намекнуло: или намекнуло, что - это если человек ведет диалоги с облаками бабочек или знаками, странное повествование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Рассеянное облако бабочек намекнуло **на то, что надо идти к переливающейся двери впереди.***

По грамматике верным представляется  такой вариант, что видно из словаря:

**НАМЕКАТЬ,** -аю, -аешь; **нсв. (кому) на что**. Говорить, действовать намёками, делать намёки. Ему намекали, что пора на пенсию. Я намекала на стеснённые обстоятельства. // на кого-что. Говоря намёками, иметь в виду кого-, что-л. Н. на соседа. **<Намекнуть,** -ну, -нёшь; св. Однокр.

Или так: *Рассеянное облако бабочек намекнуло: **надо идти к переливающейся двери впереди.***  Это БСП.

Или так: *Рассеянное облако бабочек намекнуло: **иди к переливающейся двери впереди.***  Вариант с дословным высказыванием (упрощенное оформление прямой речи).

**P. S.** Еще один вариант — это использовать глагол "намекнуть" в особом (образном) значении: ***велело, предложило (что?) идти**.* Тогда это дополнение, выраженное инфинитивом.

Comment: он предложил идти // здесь инфинитив - не дополнение

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Как всегда, по делу.

Answer (score 2):

В народе не зря закрепилось выражение "Это как бы намекает", потому что просто "Это намекает" режет слух. Облако не может ни намекнуть, ни нашептать, ни подтолкнуть, ни сподвигнуть. Действие намекнуть не может. Картина намекнуть не может. Собака намекнуть не может. Иногда, встречаются выражения типа: Большие облака, ветер, ласточки низко над землей - все это намекает на приближение дождя. Но даже в такой форме бросается в глаза вычурность глагола намекать без активного субъекта действия.

С другой стороны в русском полно фраз типа
`Это подтолкнуло меня...`, `Что-то подсказывает мне` (Хотя "Облако подтолкнуло меня не работает", но скажем мысль подтолкнуть уже может). То есть иногда мы видим тенденцию ломки смысла в угоду простоты предложения. Но наш случай совсем уж беспредел. Хотя вполне литературным будет образное `Облако бабочек (перед глазами) подсказало мне идти к переливающейся двери впереди`/`Облако бабочек указывало на то, что нужно идти к переливающейся двери впереди`. Если хочется совсем уж точных формулировок, то `Облако бабочек было намеком идти к переливающейся двери впереди`

PS. Ах да, если облако в буквальном смысле намекнуло, то есть имело цель показать, как разумный субъект, тогда конечно можно: Рассеяное
облако людей в коридоре намекнуло мне идти смелее вперед за зарплатой к переливающейся золотом двери позади. Бабочки тоже не будь дураки, намекали как могли, по научению либо недоумию не известно

Comment: Согласен, "невербальный намек" - это нонсенс.

Comment: Спасибо за ценный комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

Существительное намек может использоваться как синоним слова  «признак». Неявные, почти незаметные признаки, - намеки: на завершение процесса / на приближение непогоды / на...
Намекают – дают знать или почувствовать, наводят (на мысль), направляют (на цель, предмет поиска) как правило – словом.
Показывать направление движения «намеками» - сомнительная затея, но еще более странным выглядит сочетание «переливающиеся двери».
«Рассеянное облако» - неплохое сочетание, но его портит близость с:

«Рассеянная туча — это метеорологический термин, который обозначает облачность с повышенным количеством слоев облаков».
Источник: https://yacht-sail.ru/chto-znachit/cto-takoe-rasseyannaya-tuca

В исходной фразе хотелось бы подменить: «рассеянное» на «полупрозрачное», «намекнуло» на «повлекло», «двери» на «блики». Например так:

«Трепещущее полупрозрачное облако бабочек, то и дело слегка расступаясь, влекло их вперед, в направлении двери, на поверхности которой переливались и пульсировали блики таинственного света».

Вариант фразы получился многословным, но чтобы формулировать короче – требуется больше усердия...

Comment: Спасибо, поняла вас. Интересный вариант получился )